# Recreate lost key for android app

Tags: android, key, keystore

My friend has lost the `KEY` file of Android App and now he want to update the App on Google Play,
I do some Google and i find out it's not possible to Update the App now. But is it possible to recreate `KEY` with same information like password and etc...

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: This means only option i have is resubmit my app to the market under a new key.??

Comment: yes. It means you have to upload your application as new (other)  application. Where you need to change your package name too... but better option is, before doing this contact Play support if they provide some ulternatives by using your developer account.

Comment: i agree with @PankajKumar try to second option it will be help ful!